# Rank of $J$ from knowledge of rank of $J^{\top}A J$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\underline{\text{Problem}}:$ Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be symmetric, full rank, and indefinite. Given $J\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times n}$ for which $n<N$ and that the rank of $J^{\top}AJ$ is $k<n$, can we conclude that the rank of $J$ is $k$?

$\underline{\text{What I have done}}$: this question can be answered "yes", when $A$ is positive definite as for any $x$ in the kernel of $J^{\top}A J$ a $(n-k)$ dimensional space we have $x^{\top}(J^{\top}A J)x=0=(Jx)^{\top}A(Jx)$ but when $A$ is positive definite this only occurs when $Jx=0$. This allows us to conclude that the dimension of the kernel of $J$ is at least $(n-k)$. The kernel of $J$ being greater than $(n-k)$ would be inconsistent with the dimension of the kernel of $J^{\top}AJ$ being $(n-k)$.

$\underline{\text{Challenge}}:$
I have yet to extending this argument for the case when $A$ is indefinite. Any thoughts, references or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As $A$ is indefinite, $x^TAx=0$ for some nonzero vector $x$. Now let $J=xy^T$ for some nonzero vector $y$. Then $J^TAJ=0$ but the rank of $J$ is one, not zero.

Comment: @user1551, do think it is true that for indefinite full rank $A$ that the rank of $J$ is greater than or equal to $J^{\top}AJ$?

Comment: That has nothing to do with indefiniteness or the rank of $A$. In general $\operatorname{rank}(XY)\le\min\{\operatorname{rank}(X),\operatorname{rank}(Y)\}$. Therefore $\operatorname{rank}(J^TAJ)\le\min\{\operatorname{rank}(J^T),\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(J)\}\le\operatorname{rank}(J)$.